# Constant boolean variables in multivariate time series observations

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, data-preprocessing

I am observing multivariate time series with some of its variables being boolean.
One example of such observation has its var1=1 during all time series, and another observation has var2=0 for example during all time series. So what I mean is all observations must have all its boolean variables constant.
My question is should these variables be somehow preprocessed or it is totally fine to fit nn with such multivariate time series data?
Thank you in advance. I am newbie in these things.

Comment: "one example of such observation has its var1=1 during all time series" can you clarify? You mean, there's a multivariate time series, and one of those variables is equal to 1 at every single time point, and the second = 0 at all time points, right? (and then there are some others hopefully that are not constant?)